# WebCam image is Fuzzy

Tags: 16.04, webcam, 32-bit, lts, versions

I use a Samsung R519 Laptop with an integrated webcam (Webcam SCB-0320N). The image from the WebCam is fuzzy. How can I control the Webcam settings?
.
Version of Ubuntu Installed
Version 16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus) 32-bit
Noyau Linux 4.4.0-24-generic i686
MATE 1.12.1

Ram : 1.9 GBytes
Processor : Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU T4200 @ 2.00GHz × 2

Originally this laptop ran under Windows Vista installé.

Comment: Have you tried running it in Windows or anything else?  I know it might sound like an obvious thing but it could be dirty, even on the inside.  Many webcams have a small vent that can let dust in.

Comment: I no longer have Windows to do any such tests.  In  fact, I moved to Ubuntu to get rid of windows !!!

Comment: Did you use the webcam just before changing?  And was it a clear picture?

Comment: At the time in 2010 when I bought this laptop, Windows never really worked as the Chinese seller did not have a registration number from Microsoft which i didn't relaize at the time. So I really don't know whether the Webcam even worked on Windows. So I installed Ubuntu and my laptop works fine except for the built-in Webcam.

Comment: From the sounds of it, I'm willing to bet the camera is just very low quality, or like I mentioned before, it's dirty.  You could try downloading a bootable USB ISO from another distro and see if the webcam works.  Try [Ubuntu Gnome 14.04](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-gnome/releases/14.04/release/), it comes with webcam software called `Cheese`.  If it's also fuzzy there, then I'd bet it's the hardware and not software.

Comment: It is possible that the camera is of very low quality. In previous versions of Ubuntu   12.04 and 14.04, the WebCam image was always fuzzy in both Skype and Google  Hangouts as it is in Cheese (Ubuntu Mate 16.04).  I'll get a friend to check out whether the camera is dirty.

Comment: what do you mean by fuzzy ? Are pictures fuzzy, or do you just have low framerate ? Maybe you could attach a small video to make your question more precise ?

Comment: He means blurred. I have the same problem in Ubuntu 20.04 and Dell Latitude 5501